# No response with angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am newbie and trying to get my local data via very simple angular script. I reach my data, and see it on browser in json format, with entering http address directly to browser. So, i think my laravel api is working.

Here is my angularjs and index.html code that having trouble.

```
      function getKat($http, $scope)
        {
        $http.get('http://3burcak.dev/api/v1/kategori')
        .success(function(data)
        {
            $scope.items = data;
                            debugger;

        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config)
            {
                             debugger;

            });
        }
```

and index.html

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="getKat">
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                {{ item.id }}
            </li>
        </div>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When i inspect it with firebug, i see that falls into .error method and see no data and status 0.

Interesting thing is for me, if i change http address from  http://3burcak.dev/api/v1/kategori to  https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos then i inspect debugger falls into .success method and thus, i get all data from api.github.... address.

As i said, i am noob and my api address work properly if i hit directly to browser.

What is problem with this code? 
Thanks all.

Comment: Have a look at the request in the Network tab of Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools. There should be an error message as a response to the failed request. Or do you mean that by "no data"? There is usually also an output on the console.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder i have looked there.i get no error, i get 200OK but there is no data, also it falls .error method with no data and no error...

Comment: Do you request from same origin or another origin(cross origin)?

Comment: @SoheilGh what do you mean with origin? i request from local machine to 127.0.0.1. so, same place.

Comment: In your code, it looks like you're not loading from 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. It was CORS problem. After adding

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

It has been worked. Thanks.